# JBoss - App deployment ignoring fasterxml exclusions

Tags: java, jackson, jboss, jboss7.x, jackson-databind

I've got an app deployed to a `JBoss 7.2` instance that's explicitly using a defined fasterxml.jackson library: `'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.6'` However during runtime, I'm getting an error for a different version of jackson: `2.9.10.4-redhat-00001`. The one that's loaded as a JBoss Module.

How do I exclude this from being used by the app completely? I've performed the following and none seem to work:

1. Excluding all other jackson libraries from being pulled down from maven.
2. Forcing the correct jackson library into the WAR/lib folder during the build.
3. Calling out all jackson libraries as `<exclusion></exclusion>` in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`
4. I even went as far as converting the app to use `jackson codehaus` but still the error for `jackson:2.9.10.4-redhat-00001` persists.

**Error**

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2022-01-21T19:00:00Z')  at [Source: (org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse$InputStreamWrapper); line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.app.domainobjects.proxy.Object["body"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind@2.9.10.4-redhat-00001//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.picketbox"/>
            <module name="org.wildfly.clustering.singleton"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.server"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.msc"/>
        </dependencies>
         <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.classmate" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="app.war">
         <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.classmate" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to exclude the jackson default implementation via jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```